# Storing random numbers in an array of length 25

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to create an array of length 25, and generate a random number every 1 second and add it to this array.

However, I want that once the length of array is reached, the old values start being replaced with the newly random generated values.  This is where I have arrived so far, I am not that familiar with javascript, so any improvements are welcome:

```
var arr = [];
arr.length = 25;

function generate() {
   arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
}
setInterval(generate, 1000);
```

Can anyone tell me how I can enforce the length of the array to 25 and once this length is reached start replacing old values with new ones?  I need that the new values are always added to the end of the array as these will be used to generate a graph.

Thanks

Comment: When you say 'start replacing old values with new ones' do you mean starting from the first value? Or replace any random existing value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just remove the first element if the array is of length 25 using **[shift<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)**

```
function generate() {
 if( arr.length == 25 ) arr.shift();
 arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
}
```

Comment: `arr = arr.shift();` should be `arr.shift();`

Comment: @megawac - Thanks, it is still early here :)

Answer (score 2):

You can check array `length` before you add elements in array. When array size of array reaches `25` you can set indexer variable to zero again.

```
var arr = [];
var i = 0;       
function generate() {
   if(arr.length < 25)
      arr[i++] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   else 
      i=0;
}
```

As @megawas suggested you can use remainder by dividing i by 25

```
var arr = [];
var i = 0;       
function generate() {      
      arr[(i++)%25] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
```

Comment: or you can just do `(i++)%25`

Comment: "I need that the new values are always added to the end of the array" This wont happen though because using an iterator approach will stripe the array not append to it.

Comment: I am still not sure what exactly he wants, if he wants elements after 25 to be added on last location of array?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
var arr = []
var arr_position = 0
var arr_length = 25

function generate() {
    arr[arr_position] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1
    if(arr_position == arr_length-1){
        arr_position = 0
    } else {
        arr_position++
    }
}

setInterval(generate, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];
var constant = 25;

function generate() {
   arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
   if(arr.length == constant){
      arr.splice(0,1);
   }
}
setInterval(generate, 1000);
```